# Download csv file from server using curl in php

Tags: php, csv, curl

I am struck with this. I want to download a csv file from url using curl. I have referred all the answer in stackoverflow and tried all. But not getting what i am expected. i have the following code.

```
define("COOKIE_FILE", "cookie.txt");
$path = "settlement_file/test.csv";
set_time_limit(0);
$fp = fopen ($path, 'w+');//This is the file where we save the    information
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));//Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
curl_exec($ch); // get curl response
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: why using curl when file_get_contents() is the better way for this situation?

Comment: Url i am using, use cookies for login verification.

Comment: @vishunu lal and where is your auth with curl?

Comment: @donald123: I have another one set of code which will post the login details and creates cookie file. i have given the cookie file as an option for this curl and tried. but didnt get any desired output.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` statement. It makes `curl_exec` return the data instead of writing it to a file. Since it comes after the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);` it overrides that, so just remove the former line.